# Pandas Dataframe displays results inside brackets with commas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, jaydebeapi

I am reading data into dataframe using `pd.read_sql()`. The
database is Oracle and the Oracle connectivity module is [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/).

Issue:
The connection is successful and I am able to retrieve data as well.
But when I print the dataframe, it looks different like below

```
df[['APPL_ID','ACTV_IND','LST_UPDT_TS']]

(A, P, P, L, _, I, D)   (A, C, T, V, _, I, N, D)    (L, S, T, _, U, P, D, T, _, T, S)
0   101 (Y) 2012-05-29 11:04:51.110840
1   102 (Y) 2013-10-04 18:42:39.143024
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using `jpype` with `jaydebeapi`, since I have seen this exact behavior in such a setting before (see also [this SO answer and the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66955290/14015737)).

You can either deal with the symptoms (see other answer) or prevent the problem from occurring in the first place, by changing your connection, e.g. in one of the following two ways:

1. Use `jaydebeapi` without `jpype`:

   When this problem happened to me, I noticed that the use of `jpype` was both the cause and not necessary after all. I had the driver as a `.jar` file locally and my connection worked fine without `jpype`:

   ```
   import jaydebeapi as jdba
   import pandas as pd
   import os

   db_host = 'db.host.com'
   db_port = 1521
   db_sid = 'YOURSID'

   jar=os.getcwd()+'/ojdbc6.jar'

   conn = jdba.connect('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver', 
                   'jdbc:oracle:thin:@' + db_host + ':' + str(db_port) + ':' + db_sid, 
                   {'user': 'USERNAME', 'password': 'PASSWORD'}, 
                   jar
                   )

   df_jay = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM YOURSID.table1', conn)

   conn.close()
   ```

   This created the dataframe correctly.
2. Use `cx_Oracle` instead:

   The issue also does not occur if I use `cx_Oracle` to connect to the Oracle db:

   ```
   import cx_Oracle
   import pandas as pd
   import os

   db_host = 'db.host.com'
   db_port = 1521
   db_sid = 'YOURSID'

   dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(db_host, db_port, db_sid)
   cx_conn = cx_Oracle.connect('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', dsn_tns)

   df_cxo = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM YOURSID.table1', con=cx_conn)

   cx_conn.close()
   ```

   Note: For `cx_Oracle` to work you have to have the [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/de/database/technologies/instant-client.html) installed and properly set up (see e.g. [cx_Oracle documentation for Ubuntu](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#oracle-instant-client-zip-files)).

Comment: Thank you! I used option 1 and it worked.

Comment: You're very welcome, glad to help. But there is no need to say "thank you" in a comment. If you find an answer helpful, you can decide to show that to other users by [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you wish.